# Not run after await

Tags: reactjs, email, async-await

After the first await the code stops running this is my code:

```
handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { name, number, email, message } = this.state;

    try {
        await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/send", {
            name,
            number,
            email,
            message
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        this.setState({ result: "There was an error, try again." });
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/result");
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ result: data });
    } catch (ex) {
       this.setState({ result: "There was an error, try again." });
    }
};
```

but the second await in the second try doesn't work.
Can someone help me

Comment: What does it mean by not running? Is there some error showing?

Comment: No the second part of the code (fetch....) doesn't run. There is not error

Comment: @MatteoPagani what's the result of the first await? That will help you understand why the second doesn't run.

Comment: i want send email to node with axios. the email works but the second part where i fetch the result (to return in my react app like 'mail sent' or 'there was an error') douesn't work

Comment: Do you know if the second request is actually being made? It's possible you're stuck on the first await. Try adding a debugger after the post request and see if you ever hit it.

Comment: I tried to add a console.log and it is not done

Comment: try this and see if you get any error in console catch (error) {
       console.log(error)
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two different concepts here - async/await and promise chaining. If you want to go with async/await, try something like this.

```
try {
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/result");
  let data = await response.json();
  this.setState({ result: data });
} catch (ex) {
  this.setState({ result: "There was an error, try again." });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in my node code i put res at the same url (.../send) and it works